# Equal derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Does there exist a nonconstant function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$? How about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Edit: I should say this is not for homework. I just thought of these two problems. I was wondering if they are true.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you are typically expected to show your own attempt at the problem too, not just push all the work to MathSE members. At least show you've made an effort to address the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: $f=x+y+z+C$ and $f=x+y+2z+C$ .

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

$f(x,y,z)=e^{x+y+z}$ -- (in fact, this one satisfies $f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$

and your second question: $f(x,y,z)=e^{x+y+2z}$